# Handling multiple records and models trought ajax in a form using Yii

Tags: design-patterns, yii, multiple-records

This must be a common scenario somehow:

On a form called **Subscription** we have, among other subscription related fields, this:

Select How many **foo** you need: 
 *Select box with 5 options from [1] to [5*]

If the user selects **2** then, via Ajax the following should appear:

```
<!-- for 1 -->
 <input type="text" id="name1">Name of thing</input>  
 <input type="text" id="age1">Age of thing</input>  

<!-- for 2 -->
 <input type="text" id="name2">Name of thing</input>  
 <input type="text" id="age2">Age of thing</input>
```

So, we have two tables (Subscription, foo), several records to be inserted on one of those tables (foo), all this on a single form.

Does anyone is kind enough to sketch a quick example on how should we properly deal with scenarios like the described above?

The closer that I found was this, but, doesn't cover multiple models nor ajax. :/
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

Really hope someone could give me a push here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have look at the chapter [Handling variable number of inputs](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=N94oPslRUocC&pg=PT180&lpg=PT180#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the book **Yii 1.1 Application Development Cookbook**

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with an analog problem at the moment.
In general, I think you should be able to loop over the models. Every form, will have field names like: Object[$i]['number'] ($i = counter). The ajax request can be a render partial, I think, no?

If I find it tonight, I'll post some code here.